# ASP.NET MVC3: Publish target is not a valid disk path or URL. Format of URL cannot be determined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, url, deployment, publish, target

I am trying to publish a website migrated from MVC2 to MVC3 using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  In the Publish section of the Publish Web dialog, I have the following settings:

Publish Method = FTP
Target Location = ftp.akwimemorial.org
with user name and password credentials.

However, when I click on the Publish button, I get the following error:

"The publish target is not a valid disk path or URL.  The format of the URL cannot be determined".

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

I needed to use ftp://ftp.akwimemorial.org as the target location instead of  ftp.akwimemorial.org.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Very bad user experience - Visual Studio did not do a good job here. There was no hint on the expected format.